# How can give the path of a html file in the local computer in GWT Frame

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm using the following code to get a html file in GWT,

```
Frame frame = new Frame("path of the file");
```

But i got 404 error. How can give the specified path of a html file which is in the Desktop of my local machine in GWT Frame. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Comment: I don't know if I understand well your intention but to my sense your app running inside a browsr   can't have permission to access resources on local computer .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand well your intention but to my sense your app running inside a browsr   can't have permission to access resources on local computer . If you want to do cross site you perhaps can have a look to [that](http://lmonson.com/blog/?p=51) and [this](https://github.com/bradrydzewski/gwt-filesystem).